# Data consistency and using session instead of foreign key and relations

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a database with 15 tables that are connected between each other by different relations.

The main table is the login table:

```
login_id

user_name

user_pass

area_id
```

The area_id means that each area have it's own user and password so each action made, we can figure out in which area it happened.

Now instead of connecting all 15 tables into the login table with 1 to many relation and area_id is the foreign key, can I save the area_id in a session (because the backend language is PHP) and add it in each table without the relation.

So now, the user_info table contains:

```
name

address

phone

mother_name

contact

alternative_contact

area_id
```

But here this table is not connected directly to login table but it contains a similar field **area_id** and which it's value is added from session, and so we can now create a query by saying:

```
SELECT something FROM login JOIN user_info WHERE user_info.area_id = login.area_id
```

Does this makes data consistent or should I connect the login table with all other tables ?

Comment: In DB theory, a relation is a mathematical structure that is represented by a table, not a connection between tables. FK constraints are integrity constraints and don't prescribe how tables are joined.

Comment: Yes I know, so my aspect would be right.

Comment: `WHERE user_info.area_id = login.area_id` _is_ a "relation" or "connection", whether or not you use Foreign keys, or even Indexes.